# Draw gradient inside UIView draw() with swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, gradient

I want to put a gradient background in all my views.

The way that I thought to do this without the need to create a IBOutlet of a view in all view controllers is to create a new class from UIView, and inside the draw() I put the code that makes a CAGradientLayer in the view.

So, in the interface builder I just need to select the background view and set its class as my custom class. It works so far.

My question is if I can do that without problems. Somebody knows is it ok?
Because the model file that inherit from UIView come with the comment: 
//Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.

And I don't know if create a layer counts. Or if draw() is only to low level drawing or something like that. Do not know nothing about the best usage of the draw() func.

This is the code:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let layer = CAGradientLayer()
        layer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.frame.width, height: self.frame.height)

        let color1 = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 39/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1)
        let color2 = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 91/255, blue: 168/255, alpha: 1)

        layer.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        self.layer.addSublayer(layer)
    }
```

Comment: You need the location property for your gradient layer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` to configure the startColor and endColor properties from the `Storyboard`. Use `CGGradient` which specifies colors and locations instead of CAGradientLayer if you want to draw in draw(_ rect:) method. The Simple Gradient class and `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` function would look like this

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable 
class GradientView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var startColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 39/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1)
    @IBInspectable var endColor: UIColor = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 91/255, blue: 168/255, alpha: 1)

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

      let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
      let colors = [startColor.cgColor, endColor.cgColor]

      let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

      let colorLocations: [CGFloat] = [0.0, 1.0]

      let gradient = CGGradient(colorsSpace: colorSpace,
                                     colors: colors as CFArray,
                                  locations: colorLocations)!

      let startPoint = CGPoint.zero
      let endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bounds.height)
      context.drawLinearGradient(gradient,
                          start: startPoint,
                            end: endPoint,
                        options: [CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0)])
    }
}
```

you can read more about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_shadings/dq_shadings.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH207-TPXREF101) and [tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/162313/core-graphics-tutorial-part-2-gradients-contexts)

Comment: Thank you. I think it is the closer that I was looking for. And works great.

Comment: And good idea to use IBInspectable and IBDesignable, makes it perfect.

Comment: Great it helped. Now you can configure values from storyboard for different views.

Comment: I get an error on colorSpace which says: "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". what am I doing wrong? @SuhitPatil

Comment: @SuhitPatil I get 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value' due to 'options' having an empty array. I'm using Swift 5.

Comment: @curiously77 updated the code to fix the crash. Thanks.

Comment: @SuhitPatil Is it because of Swift 5? Because I have the same issue with another argument of 'CGGradient' called 'Locations'. I get this error 'Cannot convert value of type 'CGGradientDrawingOptions' to expected element type 'CGFloat'' when I substitute '[]' for '[CGGradientDrawingOptions(rawValue: 0)]'.

Comment: @curiously77 not sure it's because of Swift 5. in drawLinearGradient method the options are declared as an enum of the type OptionSetType. So you pass here CGGradientDrawingOptions enum type or  set containing elements from the enum. We specify empty [ ] when we don't wan't to apply any options. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36323615/cannot-convert-value-of-type-int-to-expected-argument-type-cggradientdrawingopti this issue for more details.

Comment: Plus I have shared the tutorial and documentation links as well, please check in case if you have any doubts. Try out the above code in playground.

Comment: Short and simple. Found it two days later. Youtuber's want to make it super complicated with 100s of overriden methods and tools etc. Sad how much easier Android dev is.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding a CAGradientLayer inside the `draw` function.

If you want to add a gradient to a view then the easiest way is to do it with a  layer (like you are doing) but not like this...

You should add it to your view as part of the init method and then update its frame in the layout subviews method.

Something like this...

```
class MyView: UIView {
    let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = {
        let l = CAGradientLayer()
        let color1 = UIColor(red: 4/255, green: 39/255, blue: 105/255, alpha: 1)
        let color2 = UIColor(red: 1/255, green: 91/255, blue: 168/255, alpha: 1)
        l.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]
        return l
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        gradientLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But with this code, the gradient aren't showed. I just have a white background (the color of my view itself).
I need to call the init(frame) some where? I think it is never called.
The xcode require to me put a init(coder), may I call the init(frame) inside its?

Comment: if you want to support IB/storyboards then you'll need to support both `init(frame:)` and `init(coder:)` - i typically have a function called `setup()` that is called by both initializers.

Answer (score 1):

I would create UIView extension and apply it when needed.

```
extension UIView {
        func withGradienBackground(color1: UIColor, color2: UIColor, color3: UIColor, color4: UIColor) {
            let layerGradient = CAGradientLayer()

            layerGradient.colors = [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor, color3.cgColor, color4.cgColor]
            layerGradient.frame = bounds
            layerGradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.5, y: 1.5)
            layerGradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
            layerGradient.locations = [0.0, 0.3, 0.4, 1.0]

            layer.insertSublayer(layerGradient, at: 0)
        }
}
```

Here you can change func declaration to specify `startPoint`, `endPoint`and `locations` params as variables.

After that just call this method like

```
gradienView.withGradienBackground(color1: UIColor.green, color2: UIColor.red, color3: UIColor.blue, color4: UIColor.white)
```

*P.S.*
Please note that you can have as much colors as you want in `colors` array

Comment: But with this extension I will need to create a outlet of the view in all view controller to call the gradient func. i want to avoid that. Thanks anyway.